# Can I use data from blade inside javascript code

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

Can I pass blade variable to javascript code:

```
var deadline = 'Octobar 20 2015 22:00:00 UTC+0200';
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);  
    };
```

How can I pass `deadline`variable with `{{$article->auction_end}}` ?
Is that possible or do I need to make an ajax call ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I usually like to do because I think it's cleaner than directly setting php variables as javascript variables is to generate a meta tag for it instead.

```
<meta name="deadline" content="{{ $article->auction_end }}" >
```

Then you can grab it later with jquery.

```
var deadline = $('meta[name=deadline]').attr('content');
```

This way is especially helpful if you want to break out the js into its own file rather than have a bunch of javascript in your views.

However, yes it is possible to set your javascript variable with PHP, assuming your javascript is inside your .blade.php file...

```
var deadline = '{{ $article->auction_end }}';
```

Comment: nice trick! btw, for HTML5 ` />` is not nessesary:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/1331425.